# List monad instance that appends elements

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to make a Monad instance of List that would work like this?

```
foo = do
  [1]
  [2]
  [3]

main = print foo -- prints [1,2,3]
```

To make this work, I would need a constraint that every array have the same type: `[Int]`.

Comment: Is there any way to change the type of `(>>)` to `m a -> m a -> m a`?

Comment: You can actually achieve this with `-XRebindableSyntax`, but it won't have anything to do with monads then. @Carsten, this should be an answer! (Actually, it's more accurate to say it will ignore both `1` and `2` – the list spines are _not_ ignored!)

Comment: @VladtheImpala Does it have to be the list monad?  The writer monad works similarly as `foo = do { tell [1]; tell [2]; tell [3] }`, if you then did `execWriter foo` you would get `[1, 2, 3]` returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the effect you want with `mtl`'s `Writer` monad and nothing crazy:

```
type AutoList a = Writer [a] ()

foo :: AutoList Int
foo = do
    tell [1]
    tell [2]
    tell [3]

toList :: AutoList a -> [a]
toList = execWriter

main = print (toList foo)
```

However, you can do an awful hack with `-XOverloadedLists` to sort-of get it with just list literals.  The caveat is that you have to give a type signature on each line:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLists #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
module AutoList where

import GHC.Exts
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Writer

newtype AutoListM a r = AutoListM (Writer [a] r) deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)

type AutoList a = AutoListM a ()

instance IsList (AutoList a) where
    type Item (AutoList a) = a
    fromList = AutoListM . tell
    fromListN n = AutoListM . tell . take n
    toList (AutoListM w) = execWriter w


foo :: AutoList Int
foo = do
    [1] :: AutoList Int
    [2] :: AutoList Int
    [3] :: AutoList Int


main = print (toList foo)
```

It has to be a monad for the do notation, but without the type signatures it can't figure out that it should be `r ~ ()` in `AutoListM Int r`.  With explicit type signatures it's able to figure everything out, but I doubt this is the solution you really want, and it's more work than just use `Writer` and `tell`.  Also, it's just something you really shouldn't do.

Comment: Makes sense. I've used Writer for this before, I'll use that again. Thanks!